# Chrome Extension: Reading text between a tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to making Chrome extensions. I'm trying to read text between a class tag, such as:

```
<div id="AssetThumbnail" class="thumbnail-holder"  data-3d-thumbs-enabled data-url="/thumbnail/asset?assetId=111795617&amp;thumbnailFormatId=6912&amp;width=320&amp;height=320" style="width:320px; height:320px;">
    <span class="thumbnail-span" **data-3d-url=**"/asset-thumbnail-3d/json?assetId=111795617"  data-js-files='http://js.rbxcdn.com/a552a24cb2c7a47ad748fd129a2e9624.js.gzip' ><img  class='' src='http://t7.rbxcdn.com/7cfa58047697662d12f33d68b71e5f42' /></span>
    <span class="enable-three-dee btn-control btn-control-small"></span>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the text from **data-3d-url=**. I have surrounded it with asterisks in my code so you can see what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you could retrieve an attribute like that with the following snippet.

`alert($('.thumbnail-span').attr("data-3d-url"));`

You can then change the alert function to set a variable or whatever else you want to use that value for.

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/r1umr3s5/1/

Comment: Okay! That fixed it and I have one more problem.  `contentInput.onclick = function(){
 alert($('.thumbnail-span').attr("data-3d-url"));
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({
  action: "EditContent",
  type: assetType,
  name: assetName, 
  content: contentData
 })

}` I have this code but when I click the button I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `

Comment: Do you have a copy of jQuery in your extension's folder, and is it entered in the "js:" section of your manifest.json like this: `"js": ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js"]` (or whatever the filename you chose is) ?

Comment: Yeah, I do. Do I need to inject it into something or?

Comment: If you're modifying content in a tab or retrieving content from it you'll likely need `"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["*://*"], 
  "js": ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js"]}]`.

Comment: @user3851593 1) `"js"` atrribute is an array. Use it as such. 2) jQuery **must** be injected first. So, it becomes `"js": ["jquery.js", "item.js"]`

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm going to try to send httpget requests now!

Comment: @Xan Good call. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that other other script would actually be referencing the jQuery file. Thanks!